# How can I create an instance of a generic enum in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums, rawrepresentable

I'm trying to write a function in swift that creates a rawValue enum in a generic function like this:

```
enum STATE: String {
    case OK = "OK"
    case ERROR = "ERROR"
}

func createEnum<E: RawRepresentable>(rawValue: T.Type) {
    return E(rawValue: rawValue) // compiler error 
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Your function has a return type of `Void`, for one thing.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but that was just a typo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted, your function needs a return type if you want it to `return` anything. Since you seem to want to use the function to create a value of the specified enum type, that return type should probably be either `E` or `E?`. (You're wrapping `init?(rawValue:)`, which returns an optional because `rawValue` may not map to one of the enum cases. So you either want to pass the optional through to your caller or have some logic in your function to unwrap it and handle the nil case.)

Your parameter `rawValue` also needs a real type — `T.Type` is not a fully qualified type in your declaration. You can get at the raw value type of the enum using the `RawValue` typealias that the `RawRepresentable` protocol (which you've already given as a generic constraint) defines.

So, here's your function:

```
func createEnum<E: RawRepresentable>(rawValue: E.RawValue) -> E? {
     return E(rawValue: rawValue) 
}
```

Note that if you try something like this:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case One = 1
    case Two = 2
}
createEnum(1)
createEnum<Foo>(1)
```

It won't work — the first one doesn't specify which specialization of the generic function to use, and the second doesn't work because Swift doesn't allow manual specialization of generic functions. Instead, you have to set it up so that type inference does its thing:

```
let f: Foo? = createEnum(1)
someFuncThatTakesAFoo(createEnum(1))
```

Comment: Footnote: presumably your "real" intended use of this function puts some useful logic inside — otherwise there's not much point to just putting a generic wrapper around `init(rawValue:)`, because you still need to know (or be able to infer) the enum type at the call site.